# Download a table created in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download

I need to give users a set of 60 observations. I have a master table that I want to to subset these 60 observations from. So, (1) I host the master table as a published csv file on google drive. (2) Write a shiny code to subset 60 values in R studio. The user will have to enter a group ID that I use as set.seed and ensure that the user sees the same subset every time he / she attempts to get the 60 observations. And, it also helps me keep track of the observations that the user has.

The code works fine and I am able to show the subset table. But, I am not able to get the download to work. I saw a post that says renderTable create an HTML table that cannot be downloaded and I should create the table outside it. I tried using reactive to do this, but it did not work and kept giving various errors. For example:

```
"cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame"
```

Will appreciate any help of this - even if someone can please point out to what I should read and try to make this work.

```
library(shiny)

db1 <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS94xYLix6bDUNNXAgHejdQ-CcWi-G4t25nfxuhRZF57TloC8NwVgnperBB9-U-IuDvMcOnvdc9iavU/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv")


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("MnM"),

    # Sidebar to take input of group ID 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("seed","Group ID:", value = 100, min = 100, max = 999),
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
        ),

        # Show the table
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic for the table

server <- function(input, output) {
    
        
    output$table <- renderTable({
            set.seed(input$seed)
            zz <- sample(1:nrow(db1), size = 60, replace = TRUE)    
            data.frame(db1[zz,])})
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "test.csv",
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(output$table, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your table once, and then use it in your `renderTable` and `downloadHandler`. Create it as a reactive, so its available everywhere.

Note that `downloadHandler` doesn't work in RStudio's preview, view it in a browser instead. There is a button labelled 'Open in Browser' that will do this.

Here is your code with that applied:

```
library(shiny)

db1 <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS94xYLix6bDUNNXAgHejdQ-CcWi-G4t25nfxuhRZF57TloC8NwVgnperBB9-U-IuDvMcOnvdc9iavU/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv")


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("MnM"),
    
    # Sidebar to take input of group ID 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("seed","Group ID:", value = 100, min = 100, max = 999),
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
        ),
        
        # Show the table
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic for the table
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #Create dataframe
    mytable <- reactive({
        
        set.seed(input$seed)
        zz <- sample(1:nrow(db1), size = 60, replace = TRUE)    
        data.frame(db1[zz,])
        
    })
    
    #Display dataframe in table
    output$table <- renderTable({
        mytable()
    })
    
    #Download dataframe
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "test.csv",
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(mytable(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```